# Interest VS interests in THIS phrase

Tags: conjunctions, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

I understand the concept of countables and uncountables in interest(s).

- > Engineering and Math interest me.
- > Books interest him.
- > His interests include sports.
- > he only seeks his own interests.

however the OR is bothering me here.
do we say:

> Engineering **or** Business in PwC **interest** me.

or do we say:

> Engineering **or** Business in PwC **interests** me.

this is for a cover letter.

Comment: I am not sure why you would say **or** in such a circumstance, but when you use **or** for two singular nouns, the result is singular.

Comment: @JavaLatte what about if i use engineering AND business. do i say interest me?

Comment: This advice is a little bit off-topic, but do you think that you might need two cover letters? Are you expressing interest in two different positions or simply expressing that you have multiple interests?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang multiple interests it is explained in 1st part of letter

Comment: Then I would use "and." When I have multiple interests, I would list them with "and" instead of "or." Perhaps, "I'm interested in both business and engineering (at PwC)"?

Comment: If you are unsure about **"or"** use **"either"**.

Comment: When using *or*, the verb agrees with the closest subject. "Money or books are important", "Books or money is important". So when both subject is singular, the verb should be singular.

Comment: what if i use and?

Comment: @SovereignSun interests or interest for and? thank you

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang for and? thank you i think im going to just replace it, outcome is better

Comment: **Interests** of course

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple.

A conjunction ("and") always takes the plural verb:

> A cat and a dog keep [not "keeps"] you company.

In a disjunction ("or"), the verb should match the number of the noun nearest it.

> A dog or two cats keep an entire house free of mice.
>
> Two cats or a dog keeps an entire house free of mice.

If both nouns are singular, the verb is singular.

Comment: only a point is missed : when 'and' joins units of a totality, such phrases take singular verbs eg. 'life and death' or 'bread and butter'.

Comment: @BaridBaranAcharya -- perhaps you could give some quotations to illustrate the point?

Comment: Two nouns but singular idea or  single dish : milk and cookies/spaghetti and meat/peanut butter and jelly/fish and chips/horse and carriage/slow and steady/meat and potatoes/Joanna's rum and coke etc. Of course there's​ remaining compound subject but single person/thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your examples distinguish not between countable and uncountable forms of the noun "interest", but between the non-third-person-singular present form of the verb "interest" (that is, "interest") and the plural form of the noun "interest" (that is, "interests"). Relevant examples for the noun would be:

```
His main interest is golf.

His two main interests are golf and swimming.
```

As for the verb, consider that it can refer to either something that intrigues one or something that one wants to commit oneself to:

```
I am interested in what makes a movie scary.

I would be interested in a job in your company.
```

Also note that a person can have more than one interest simultaneously. If you want your audience to know that (which is not always a good idea with a cover letter, as it may make you look indecisive, or less committed to one of the departments/jobs that you're applying to), then a rewrite of the sentence would be better. Depending on what you want to say:

```
I am interested in both engineering and business.

I would be interested in studying either engineering or business.
```

The first one means that both engineering and business intrigue you. The second one means that you would be happy to commit yourself to either subject.